# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, models, nullreferenceexception

I have this code:

```
IQueryable<Dealer> dealers = db.Dealers.Include(x => x.Statuses);
this.view.Table = dealers
    .Select(x => new DealerRow
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        LastStatus = x.Statuses.FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .ToList();
```

and the line that starts with `this.view.Table = dealers` is where this exception occurs:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The stack trace is the following:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.AddDefaultColumns(Scope scope) +293
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.Wrap(Scope scope) +36
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbApplyExpression expression) +236
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbApplyExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +64
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +32
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.HandleJoinExpression(DbExpressionBinding left, DbExpressionBinding right, DbExpressionKind joinType, DbExpression joinCondition) +77
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbJoinExpression expression) +48
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbJoinExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +64
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +32
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +22
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbSortExpression expression) +76
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbSortExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +64
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +32
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +22
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression) +53
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +64
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree) +68
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +328
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +13
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +127
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) +1420
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +103
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +127
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree) +151
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator) +161
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +1027
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6() +39
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +155
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +281
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +387
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   DealersPresenter.RefreshTable() in File1.cs:98
   DealersListPage.Filter(Object sender, EventArgs e) in File2.aspx.cs:37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9659822
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

Specifically, if I comment out `LastStatus` from the select the program compiles and runs perfectly. So I'm assuming `Statuses` is the issue here.

The one to many relationship is setup like this:

```
[Table("dealers")]
public class Dealer
{

    public Dealer()
    {
        Statuses = new List<DealerStatus>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DealerStatus> Statuses { get; set; }

}
```

and:

```
[Table("dealer_statuses")]
public class DealerStatus
{

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Dealer")]
    [Column("id_dealer")]
    public int DealerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("note")]
    public string Note { get; set; }

}
```

I've read other 5 questions about it. I tried calling `Include` and similars. I've also checked that the default constructor for Dealer initializes an empty list.

What's causing this exception?

Comment: Does it also happen if you change the first line to db.Dealers.Include(x => x.Statuses).ToList(); ?

Comment: @Fabiano Adding the line "db.Dealers.Include(x => x.Statuses).ToList();" before anything else doesn't trigger the exception.

Comment: Could it be because the key property is not called DealerId and just Id? Following [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) reference it's the only difference I see.

Comment: Doesn't seem so. Just tried to name them DealerId and DealerStatusId and the same exception occurs.

Comment: Would be good to include full stack trace.

Comment: @RonaldPhilipsen The OP here is (clearly) not confused about what the NRE is, this is a problem with EF mapping that they are trying to solve.

Comment: @Evk I've added the stack trace.

Comment: Ah, that's mysql... Its EF provider is known to be very buggy, and indeed throws NullReference exceptions in innocent cases. Maybe it just cannot map your statement to sql (by the way: you don't need `Include`).

Comment: If performance and memory usage is not an issue. Just eager load the 'Statuses' collection. You can achieve that by making the property non-virtual: public ICollection<DealerStatus> Statuses { get; set; }

Comment: @Fabiano I made the property non virtual and it still throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to remove `virtual` from the collection, and other kind of eager loading, I've moved the `Select` after the `ToList` call (which will eagerly load everything) but at least it compiles and runs.

Updating to the latest 6.9.9 MySql.Data.Entity also didn't work for me.